Fitting a multidimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck pProcess
If I have a dataset X, where each row is a time point and we have several variables, say 100, (so this is a multivariate time series), what is the best way to fit a multidimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (estimate the parameters from the data X) and assess the goodness of fit?
